# Gradlew genEclipseRuns Error. Why did this happen?

Tags: minecraft-forge

I'm fairly new to modding, soo can someone help?

Forge 1.17.1.1-37.0.103. Adoptium 16.0.2.7

Ran cmd Command: gradlew genEclipseRuns

My logs:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspathCopy'.
> Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.17.1-37.0.103_mapped_official_1.17.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/Classified/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.17.1-37.0.103_mapped_official_1.17.1/forge-1.17.1-37.0.103_mapped_official_1.17.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Classified/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.17.1-37.0.103_mapped_official_1.17.1/forge-1.17.1-37.0.103_mapped_official_1.17.1.jar
  Required by:
      project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Checked the location and did not find the folder bundeled_repo

Comment: You should read the complete tutorial. Some dependencies seems missing specially the `net.minecraftforge:forge:1.17.1-37.0.103_mapped_official_1.17.1`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Install Gradle [here](https://gradle.org/install/) and reinstall Adoptium, making sure to have the "set Java home path" option to `Will Install On This Hard Drive`. Run the build again and it should work!